# Why is my Node.js (Express) app taking up to 21000ms to return for a generic GET?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have this block of code:

```
// GET - Default (root)
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log('GET request to "/"..');
    res.header('content-type', 'text/html');
    return res.end('' +
        '<h1>Welcome to the <a href="http://throneofli.es/game">Throne of Lies</a> API</h1>' +
        '<h2>Check back later for public routes.</h2>');
});
```

I tried running this in with Postman:

The results are an average of 21k to 22k ms:

[Postman Result Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljuEl.png)

Now, sometimes it's speedy, <150ms. However, most of the time, it's not. This is running off an ubuntu16LTS droplet from digitalocean. Is there something weird I'm doing? I'm still new to Node so surely it's in the code. My full code (not that much code) can be found here:

https://github.com/dylanh724/tol-node-public/blob/master/tol/server.js

**EDIT 1:** I tried using res.**send** instead of **end**, but that didn't seem to resolve anything.

Comment: *"22k ms"* - Well put.

Comment: Sounds more like a problem with name resolution to me... Have you tried with an IP address instead of a hostname?

Comment: What is the hostname ? On code you have cors with     **'*.throneoflies.com'** and home page you have **<Welcome to the <a href="http://throneofli.es/game">**

Comment: On an unrelated note, your readme needs updating with regard to obtaining an SSL certificate, since you can obtain free SSL certificates from [LetsEncrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/).

Comment: Ah I didn't try ip. I still have the original version and I'll try later out of curiosity. As for host name, it was throneoflies.com (throneoflie.es is a short url service with tracking). Thanks for the Readme suggestion about ssl will look into it. If you use let's encrypt won't most browsers reject it though since it's not a certified authority?

Answer (score 1):

Resolved via a workaround : I suspect ordering had something to do with it. I revamped it using express-generator template and going MVC style. No idea why this works and the other doesn't.

PS, why downvoted?